# How can I show all data under specific category using sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

well, I have 2 Mysql table which structure is bellow :

### Table **Jobs**

```
job_id---job_cat_id---job_title---job_description---job_data----is_active
=========================================================================
1        1            title 1     description 1     2016-05-06  1
2        2            title 2     description 2     2016-05-06  0
3        2            title 3     description 3     2016-05-06  1
```

**Table job_details**

```
job_cat_id---job_cat_name
=========================
1            cat name 1
2            cat name 2
3            cat name 3
```

Now I want to show all jobs under each category from `jobs` table. E.g

**What I need to show :**

```
Job Category 1
    1. job 1 from category 1
    2. Job 2 from category 1
Job Category 2
    1. Job 3 from category 2
```

So to do this I am using following `sql` query but can't get the correct result :

```
$get_job = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT jobs.job_id, jobs.job_title, job_category.job_cat_name FROM jobs LEFT JOIN job_category ON job_category.job_cat_id = jobs.job_cat_id WHERE jobs.is_active = '1' ");        

while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($get_job) ) {

    $job_id = (int) $result['job_id'];
    $job_title = htmlspecialchars($result['job_title']);
    $job_category = htmlspecialchars($result['job_cat_name']);   

    echo "<h4>$job_category</h4>";  
    echo "<p>$job_title</p>";           
}
```

Now, It's showing me all category with all jobs but I want to show all jobs under each category.

**What is showing now :**

```
Job Category 1
    1. job 1 from category 1        
Job Category 1
    1. Job 2 from category 1
Job Category 2
    1. Job 3 from category 2
```

Comment: All you have to do is modify 2 lines of code. Check out my answer below and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I am checking it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we have to remember that the result from a `SELECT` query is a newly generated table. It is not a multi dimensional array. If it were a multidimensional array, then you could get away with printing the job category at the beginning of each new array which could be grouping up all the jobs in a single category, however since this is not the type of result obtained by the SQL `SELECT` QUERY, you are printing the job category after each line:

```
echo "<h4>$job_category</h4>";  
echo "<p>$job_title</p>";
```

**Solution:**

A solution to your problem would be to first use the `ORBER BY ASC` in your sql query:

```
$get_job = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT jobs.job_id, jobs.job_title, job_category.job_cat_name FROM jobs LEFT JOIN job_category ON job_category.job_cat_id = jobs.job_cat_id WHERE jobs.is_active = '1' ORDER BY job_cat_id ASC");
```

From there, you know that the jobs in each category should at least be grouped up next to each other (from lowest to highest like 1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3). What you can now do is have a conditional print the `$job_category` if AND ONLY IF it hasn't been printed already previously.

Change this line:

```
echo "<h4>$job_category</h4>";
```

into this line:

```
if ($previous_print != $job_category)
{
  echo "<h4>$job_category</h4>";  
  $previous_print = $job_category;
}
```

Let me know if it works now.

Comment: @shibbirahmed awesome :). If this answer is the one that worked for you, please accept it with a green checkmark so that future users know.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution may be if you just run one query using group by job_cat_id and then inside loop write another query to get desired result with where clause job_cat_id .

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 queries here. Here's an exmaple code, might need some tweaks acording to your table column names:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT `job_cat_id`, `job_cat_name`, COUNT(`jobs`.`id`) as `jobs`
          FROM `job_category`
          GROUP BY `job_cat_id`";
$get_cat = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$cats = [];
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($get_cat) ) {
    $result['jobs'] = [];
    $cats[$result['job_cat_id']] = $result;
}

$get_job = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT jobs.job_id, jobs.job_title, jobs.job_cat_id FROM jobs WHERE jobs.is_active = '1' AND `job_cat_id` IN (" . implode(',', array_keys($cats)) . ")");

while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($get_job) ) {
    $cats[$result['job_cat_id']][] = $result;
}

foreach ($cats as $cat) {
    $job_category = htmlspecialchars($cat['job_cat_name']);
    echo "<h4>$job_category</h4>";

    foreach ($cat['jobs'] as $job) {
        $job_title = htmlspecialchars($job['job_title']);
        echo "<p>$job_title</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I use only one query ?

Comment: No, you should use 2 queries here, as this is one-to-many relationship

Comment: No, I can use 1 query to get it. Check @Webeng answer :)

Comment: This might make sense with 3 jobs, but it's wrong. You shouldn't do this. Imagine what happens when you have hundreds and thousands of jobs.

Comment: will that be problem ?